# Demora para execução do código em C

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, runtime

Olá galera essa é a primeira vez que busco ajuda, bom sou um calouro de Ciência da computação e estou tendo dificuldades em um trabalho onde a professora pediu para que ajeitasse código de uma pessoa aleatória da sala, acabei pegando o código de um cara onde ele tinha que concatenar alternadamente duas LDSE.
Consegui arrumar esse código já que ele anteriormente só concatenava, porém uma coisa que achei estranho é que na hora de executar o código acabava demorando muitooo para aparecer o menu e também as vezes só aparecia quando eu aperto alguma tecla, não consigo achar o problema que possa estar causando isso então gostaria de uma ajudinha.
Esse é o código:

```
 #include < stdio.h>

 #include < stdlib.h>

 #include < string.h>

 #include < locale.h>

 #define max 9

typedef struct dadosLDSE
{
    int vlr;
    struct dadosLDSE* prox;
}sLDSE;

sLDSE* lista_insere (sLDSE* l, int i)
{
    sLDSE *aux, *auxIns;

    aux = (sLDSE *) malloc(sizeof(sLDSE));

    if (aux == NULL){
        exit (1);
    }

    aux->vlr = i;
    aux->prox = NULL;
    if(l == NULL){
        l = aux;
    }else{
        auxIns = l;
        while (auxIns->prox != NULL){
            auxIns = auxIns->prox;
        }
        auxIns->prox = aux;
    }
    return l;
}

void lista_imprime (sLDSE* l)
{
    /* nao precisa de variavel auxiliar para percorrer a lista */
    for ( ;l != NULL; l = l->prox)
        printf("%d\n", l->vlr);
}


/* concatena modificando lista */
void concatena (sLDSE* l1, sLDSE* l2)
{
    int p = 0;
    while (l1 != NULL || l2 != NULL){
        if (p%2 == 0 && l1 != NULL){
            printf ("%d \n", l1->vlr);
            l1 = l1->prox;
        }else{
            if (l1 == NULL && l2 != NULL){
                printf ("%d \n", l2->vlr);
                l2 = l2->prox;
            }
        }

        if (p%2 != 0 && l2 != NULL){
            printf ("%d \n", l2->vlr);
            l2 = l2->prox;
        }else{
            if (l2 == NULL && l1 != NULL){
                printf ("%d \n", l1->vlr);
                l1 = l1->prox;
            }
        }
        p++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int vlr;
    int resp;

    //criando lista l
    sLDSE *l;
    l = NULL;
    //criando lista l2
    sLDSE *l2;
    l2 = NULL;

//Aqui está o menu
    do{
        printf("(1) Inserir no inicio da Lista 1:\n");
        printf("(2) Inserir no inicio da Lista 2:\n");
        printf("(3) Visualizar a Lista concatenada:\n");
        printf("(4) Sair\n\n");
        printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
        scanf("%d", &resp);
        switch(resp){
            case 1: {
                    printf("Digite o valor que será inserido: ");
                    scanf("%d", &vlr);
                    l = lista_insere(l, vlr);
                    break;
            }
            case 2: {
                    printf("Digite o valor que será inserido: ");
                    scanf("%d", &vlr);
                    l2 = lista_insere(l2, vlr);
                    break;
            }
            case 3: {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\nLista 1:\n");
                    lista_imprime(l); //imprime lista l
                    printf("\n\n");
                    printf("\nLista 2:\n");
                    lista_imprime(l2); //imprime lista l2
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("\nLista concatenada:\n");
                    concatena(l,l2); //chama a função concatenar que envia as duas lista e lá faz printa as duas listas concatenadas
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
}while(resp != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em tese, o menu deveria aparecer quase que automaticamente. E eu testei o seu programa e não encontrei problema nenhum na inicialização.

Faz o seguinte, verifica quanto tempo, o programa está demorando desde o início da `função main()` até a exibição do menu. Se o intervalo for curto, o problema não estará no seu programa (E onde estará? Talvez, no seu computador, compilador, IDE, difícil saber).

Agora se o tempo for longo, testa sem o `setLocale`, embora eu realmente não acredite que  o `setLocale` poderia produzir um demora perceptível nesse caso.

Para medir o intervalo, você pode usar o tipo `clock_t` presente no header `time.h`. Confira-se:

```
int main()
{
    // inserir essa linha no início da função e não se esquecer de incluir no cabeçalho
    // #include <time.h>
    clock_t t0 = clock(); 
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int vlr;
    int resp;
    //criando lista l
    sLDSE *l;
    l = NULL;
    //criando lista l2
    sLDSE *l2;
    l2 = NULL;

//Aqui está o menu
    do{
        printf("(1) Inserir no inicio da Lista 1:\n");
        printf("(2) Inserir no inicio da Lista 2:\n");
        printf("(3) Visualizar a Lista concatenada:\n");
        printf("(4) Sair\n\n");
        printf("Digite sua opcao: ");
        clock_t t1 = clock();
        //E calcular o intervalo aqui:
        printf("\nTempo inicializacao: %f segundos: ", ((double)(t1 - t0)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
        scanf("%d", &resp);
        switch(resp){
            case 1: {
                    printf("Digite o valor que será inserido: ");
                    scanf("%d", &vlr);
                    l = lista_insere(l, vlr);
                    break;
            }
            case 2: {
                    printf("Digite o valor que será inserido: ");
                    scanf("%d", &vlr);
                    l2 = lista_insere(l2, vlr);
                    break;
            }
            case 3: {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\nLista 1:\n");
                    lista_imprime(l); //imprime lista l
                    printf("\n\n");
                    printf("\nLista 2:\n");
                    lista_imprime(l2); //imprime lista l2
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("\nLista concatenada:\n");
                    concatena(l,l2); //chama a função concatenar que envia as duas lista e lá faz printa as duas listas concatenadas
                    break;
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
}while(resp != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dizem que a IDE que estou usando é bem bugada, mas como estou usando ela desde o começo do curso acabo tendo medo de tentar migrar pra outra e ter problemas pra me adaptar sei lá nessa reta final de semestre, talvez nas férias enquanto for dar uma estudada eu teste outras, mas obrigadão pela dica!